# Gitlab to azure boards integration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is it possible to integrate Azure Boards with gitlab. I would like link my tasks/stories in azure boards to commits in gitlab (hosted version). Documentation talks about Azure REpo and GitHub integration.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hey I've been looking for a way to integrate the same, do you find any workaround?

Comment: Two years later there is still no official way to do this, but this article has a decent do-it-yourself solution: [Integrate GitLab with Azure Boards](https://francescodeliva.medium.com/integrate-gitlab-with-azure-boards-40804e15b77)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to integrate Azure Boards with gitlab

For this issue, I am afraid it is currently unachievable in azure devops. Only [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.gitlab-integration) that integrate gitlab with azure pipelines is currently provided.

When we click on the `add link` button in the `Development` of the work item, there is no `gitlab` option in the `Link type` drop-down list in the popup box.

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can comment and vote it there. Our PM and Product Group are reviewing these suggestion regularly and considering take it as plan.

Comment: In case anyone else is interested, there is a request for this feature under [Azure Boards - add support for GitLab integration as well as GitHub](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-boards-add-support-for-gitlab-integration-as/1569775)